# Terminal in Tmux is 256 color but Vim isn't

Tags: 16.04, vim, colors, tmux

I'm new to Ubuntu. Recently I installed tmux on my Ubuntu 16.04.

The terminal screen in tmux shows 256 color correctly. However, when I opened vim in tmux, the color was different from what normally showed in terminal.

I tried adding `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in my `.tmux.conf` file but the problem still exists.

**Terminal screen in tmux**:

[image: terminal_screen_in_tmux]

**Vim in terminal**:

[image: vim_in_terminal]

**Vim in tmux**

[image: vim_in_tmux]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux

Comment: @jdwolf Even if I launch tmux with -2, the color is still different in vim inside tmux.